# How to extend a F4 immigrant Visa before going to USA within 6 months

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, family, covid-19

I got my F4 visa on november 2020 and it will expire on may 15th 2020. We had booked our flight on march 30th 2020 but due to covid 19 pandemic  we were unable to go to USA. Currently India is not having any International flights..  i would like to extend my visa status.. what is the procedure and how can i do that?? 
@user102008

Answer (score 1):

US Immigrant visas cannot be extended. However:

1. Because your inability to travel to the US is for reasons *outside of your control*, you can have the visa replaced (paying once again any required fees) *before the end of the fiscal year*. You should contact the consulate that issued the visa for information about this option.
2. If you've done the above and the new visa also expires during the next fiscal year and you still weren't able to travel, you'll have to go through the whole immigrant visa process again, assuming that the original basis for eligibility still exists. This will probably take a few months. Your sponsor will not need to file a new I-130, and you will retain your original priority date.

See [9 FAM 504.10-5(A)](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM050410.html#M504_10_5_A)